# Use Font Loader in Angular

Tags: angular, font-face, webfont-loader

How do I use a font loader, such as WebFontLoader or FontFaceObserver, in Angular?

I'm not sure on what/where I need to import and how to use it in a component.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do:
`npm install webfontloader`

Then in your component you can write like this:

app.component.ts:

```
import * as WebFont from 'webfontloader';
// ...
ngOnInit(){
  WebFont.load({/* your config...*/})
}
```

Comment: You can use this anywhere, not limited to component.
Run WebFont.load(...) only once in your code, and fonts will be available in all components. I am successfully loading this from a service constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I've been configuring it in the `index.html` file itself (per the README on github)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.26/webfont.js">    
</script>
<script>
  WebFont.load({
    google: {
      families: ['Droid Sans', 'Droid Serif']
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this approach:

1. Install **fontfaceobserver** package from npm

   ```
   npm i fontfaceobserver
   ```
2. Setup font observer (**Note:** you need to use this setup once in your app)

   ```
   import FontFaceObserver from 'fontfaceobserver';

   ngOnInit(): void {
       const font = new FontFaceObserver('My Family', {
         weight: 400
       });

       font.load().then(function () {
         console.log('Font is available');
       }, function () {
         console.log('Font is not available');
       });
   }
   ```

For implementing multiple fonts observer and also more optional configurations you can take a look at this official page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fontfaceobserver

Hope this will help you.